# MySQL Select statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 values that I'm suppling my script - I want to search for any one of those datas. How do I write my query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '".$id."' or "name='".$name."';
```

my problem is escaping the quotes in the query.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use curly brackets to avoid confusion with escaping characters as follows:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '{$id}' or name = '{$name}' ";
```

You may also consider using wildcards such as `%$letter%` to search for word anywhere in the `name` field as:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '{$id}' or name LIKE '%{$name}%' ";
```

**SUGGESTTION**:
You should always use `id` fields as `integer` for better performance.

Comment: This is one awesome solution - it has everything I need. Thanks a million.

Comment: You are welcome. Please like the solution you liked the most. This would encourage us to answer as much and as relevant as possible :)

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to do it, a lot of them frowned on but generally I would stick to using MySQLi and using the

```
mysqli_real_escape_string($id)
```

function or in OOP

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'pass', 'database');
$id = $mysqli -> real_escape_string($id);
$name = $mysqli -> real_escape_string($name);
$results = $mysqli -> query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '{$id}' or "name='{$name}'");
```

Comment: You don't need the `{}` just leave them out and all will work ok, you only need them if you want to include a function result.

Comment: I put them in since they didn't specify wether it was the result of a funtion or not and it doesn't stop concatenation in any way if it isn't from a function.

Comment: If you are going to use MySQLi, why not use a prepared statement?

Comment: I was just keeping it simple for the user since prepared statements can be quite a pain and they're asking how to write a query which I'd say is a fairly good benchmark of their ability, I'd assume..

Comment: Good point. I just felt it should be at least mentioned, so she can look into upgrading to it as some point.

Answer (score 0):

[Use this fancy function, mayhaps?](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)  The examples have what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You've got an extra quote; if you want to stick with your original code (*not recommended*), try something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '".$id."' or name='".$name."'";
```

*But really you should be using parameterised queries so that you avoid possible SQL injection security issues!*

Comment: Thanks for that, I have a code that escapes the supplied data. Nice solution BTW.

Answer (score 0):

Write it as:

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '$id' or name= '$name' ";
```

Because you started with double quotes the single quotes are part of the query and the $vars are expanded.